# Angular2 observable with JSON root element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

This is my first time ever working with angular observables and I'm a bit confused on how this works.  I was given a mostly functioning angular CLI app that I just need to wire up to my already existing API.

I have a `service` with this function

```
public getApps(): Observable<ApplicationInterface[]> {
  return this.http.get(url);
}
```

Then in my `component`, I have

```
public data: ApplicationInterface[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.fetchData();
    });
  }

fetchData() {
  this.service.getApps()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
    });
}
```

My api endpoint returns a JSON structure of `{"applications": []}`

I can't seem to figure out how to access the array in that JSON hash.

If I `console.log(data)` in the `subscribe` block, it is the API response with the applications key that I expect, but if I change the data assignment to `this.data = data.applications`, `ng build` fails with `Property 'applications' does not exist on type 'ApplicationInterface[]'`

Comment: FYI, this is a memory leak waiting to happen.  this.route.params.switchMap(p => this.fetchData()).subscribe(); is how you should do it to prevent leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should design the interface to be aligned with the response. If the response is object, than you need to have it like this also in the interface.

Try something like this (using the new `HttpClient`):

```
interface ApplicationInterfaceResponse {
    applications: ApplicationInterface[];
}

public getApps(): Observable<ApplicationInterface[]> {
    return this.httpClient
        .get<ApplicationInterfaceResponse>(url)
        .map(response => {
            console.log(response.applications);
            return data.applications;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your return is of type `ApplicationInterface[]`, then it's an array of `ApplicationInterfaces`, thus does not have a property called `applications` on it. This has nothing to do with your observable; it's fine. Rather, you've mistyped your variable.

If you don't need any other properties of `data`, you can map the value:

```
public getApps(): Observable<ApplicationInterface[]> {
  return this.http.get(url).map(data => data.applications);
}
```

However, I recommend against this in most situations. If your object changes in the future, then you have to change this function and all attached subscriptions. Instead, you should create an interface for your response (your response right now does not match the type you're giving it), and use values of it as necessary.

Comment: The variable type is correct.  I need it to return an array of `ApplicationInterface`s.  What I need is to be able to create that array with the `applications` key of the returned JSON, which is not happening

Comment: Right, but the return of your observable is not an array of `ApplicationInterface`s. It's an object in which one of the properties is an array of `ApplicationInterface`s. If you don't need any other property of `data`, I'd recommend map; I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to indicate the correct form of the data that is returned by your service method since it doesn't actually return an array:

```
public getApps(): Observable<{applications:ApplicationInterface[]}> {
  return this.http.get(url);
}
```

Now in your subscribe, you can get at the array as you would expect

```
.subscribe(e => this.data = e.applications)
```